# How to get Vectorize return the results invisibly?

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a drawing function `f` that should not return any output.

```
f <- function(a=0) invisible(NULL)
f(10)
```

After vectorizing `f`, it does return `NULL`.

```
f_vec <- Vectorize(f)
f_vec(10)
[[1]]
NULL
```

How can I prevent this, i.e. make the output invisible here as well.
I could of course use a wrapper to suppress it.

```
f_wrapper <- function(a=0) {
  dummy <- f_vec(a)
}
f_wrapper(10)
```

Is there a way to avoid the wrapper and get what I want straight away?

Comment: `Vectorize` is just a wrapper for `mapply`. What's one wrapper more? `Vectorize`
 can't return an invisible value. Note that `invisible` returns "a (**temporarily**) invisible copy" (emphasis by me).

Comment: Furthermore you would not see that printed result if you assigned the output to a symbol, which is how functions are expected to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah there is.  This new version of `Vectorize` will do it:

```
Vectorize_2 <- function (FUN, vectorize.args = arg.names, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) {
  arg.names <- as.list(formals(FUN))
  arg.names[["..."]] <- NULL
  arg.names <- names(arg.names)
  vectorize.args <- as.character(vectorize.args)
  if (!length(vectorize.args)) 
    return(FUN)
  if (!all(vectorize.args %in% arg.names)) 
    stop("must specify names of formal arguments for 'vectorize'")
  FUNV <- function() {
    args <- lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1L], eval, parent.frame())
    names <- if (is.null(names(args))) 
      character(length(args))
    else names(args)
    dovec <- names %in% vectorize.args
    invisible(do.call("mapply", c(FUN = FUN, args[dovec], MoreArgs = list(args[!dovec]), 
                                  SIMPLIFY = SIMPLIFY, USE.NAMES = USE.NAMES)))
  }
  formals(FUNV) <- formals(FUN)
  FUNV
}
```

But, how did I know to do this?  Did I spend 20 minutes writing a brand new version of `Vectorize`? NOPE!  I just ran `dput(Vectorize)` to see the `R` code behind `Vectorize` and added the `invisible` where necessary!  You can do this with all `R` functions.  You don't even need the `dput`!  Just run `Vectorize`!